# Specify a plugin as gem from github in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler, gemspecs

I am including 'acts_as_rateable' gem in my Gemfile like this

```
gem 'acts_as_rateable', :git => 'git://github.com/azabaj/acts_as_rateable.git'
```

and then when I do `bundle install` it gives me this error message!

> Could not find gem 'acts_as_rateable
>   (>= 0, runtime)' in
>   git://github.com/azabaj/acts_as_rateable.git
>   (at master). Source does not contain
>   any versions of 'acts_as_rateable (>=
>   0, runtime)'

I am developing a plugin of my own, when I include that, even that gives the same error like this..

I assume this has something to do with the gemspec?

Please help

Rails version : 3.0.1
Rubygems version : 1.3.7
Bundler version : 1.0.3

let me know if you need any other details..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the repository you link to is not a RubyGem. You can get with

```
$ rails plugin install git://github.com/azabaj/acts_as_rateable.git
```

**Edit:** This answer was accurate on the date it was published. Rails 4 doesn't support plugins anymore, so you will have to make this into a local gem yourself. Bundler has some commands that will help you with it, or alternatively you can use a different library, e.g. https://github.com/anton-zaytsev/acts_as_rateable.

Comment: oh ok, got it. Does the repository need to have a .gem file, so that it becomes a rubygem?

Comment: Well at least that. But more so it should be published to RubyGems to be sure that it's stable as a gem. Github used to publish gems (but doesn't anymore) so some old gems are still there.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to pull a gem directly from GitHub, you can put this into your [GemFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072880/whats-the-use-of-gemfile-in-rails):

```
gem 'twitter', github: 'sferik/twitter'
```

Which will use the default branch. To specify the branch to use:

```
gem 'twitter', github: 'sferik/twitter', branch: 'branch_name'
```

Comment: ...and don't forget restart server.

Answer (score 2):

Jakub Hampl is right, but it seems strange to depend on git repos like that. I guess you're you making it yourself? If so, make it a real gem. It should have a acts_as_rateable.gemspec and you'll be able to depend on it like you wrote. Bundler makes your life easy, create the gemspec with

```
$ bundle gem acts_as_rateable
```

Comment: yeah bundle gem plugin_name helped in creating .gemspec .. thanks, i wan't aware of that...