# What is the use of Gemfile in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

What is the use of `Gemfile` in rails?

How to use `Gemfile`?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

During your development in Rails, there will be times where you will want to provide some functionality which is required by you, but either you don't know how to do or you don't want to implement it on your own since a lot of work has been put into its development by talented developers.

These developments which you might need (user authentication, message system, asset handlers, geolocation, pagination system, linking to exterior services such as Amazon AWS, and last but not least Rails itself) are called Ruby Gems. These are ruby software packages, not necessarily relating to Rails, but since Rails is based on Ruby, 98% of the gems can be made availble to your Rails webapp code.

Lots of gems can be found in [github](http://github.com), but its funner to search for gems via [ruby-gems](http://rubygems.org/) or [ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/)

Your `gemfile` is a list of all gems that you want to include in the project.
It is used with [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) (also a gem) to install, update, remove and otherwise manage your used gems.

The `gemfile` has another purpose - you can group gems in `:development`, `:test`, `:assets`, `:production`, etc groups and Rails will know when to include the gems. For example:

```
group :development, :test do
    gem "rspec-rails"
    gem "factory_girl_rails"
    gem "guard-rspec"
end
```

Note that on Rails 4, the `assets` group has been deprecated

These gems belong to development environment and the test environment since they are for testing the application. You don't need them available in the production environment (you could, but that will bloat the memory unnecessarily).

So - To use the `gemfile`, simply write the gem you wish to install such as

```
gem 'devise'
```

make sure to install `bundler` beforehand (in your console/cmd/ssh) with

```
$ gem install bundler
```

and then write in the console

```
bundle install
```

you will notice another gemfile appears! `Gemfile.lock` 
This file, as you will see if you open it with a text reader, lists all your gems with their version and their dependencies. This will come useful when you need to know which versions of the gems you installed.

For more reading on the `Gemfile` - [read on the bundler page](http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html)

for information regarding picking a gem you could start with [this](http://www.railstutors.com/blog/how-to-pick-the-right-ruby-gem)

Good luck and have fun!

---

**Ok, so whats this Gemfile.lock that got created?**

Gemfile.lock, as the name suggests is a locking on all the versions of all the gems that got installed. So if Gemfile is what required to be installed, the lock file is what got installed and what version are actually required to get the app up and running.

If you don't have the gems in that specific version (as specified in Gemfile.lock) rails will complain and you will have to either install the missing gems (via `bundle install`) or fix any conflicts manually (I believe bundler will give you some clues on that)

**Some things to know about `Gemfile.lock`**

- if you accidently delete it, it will get regenerated when you run `bundle install`. If you accidently delete `Gemfile`, you are out of luck.. You should use git :)
- Heroku doesn't care about Gemfile.lock since it will reinstall all gems. So for Heroku, you *must* set the gem version you want, or Heroku will always install the latest version of gem, which may cause issues
- Keep the Gemfile.lock in your project so you will always know what version of gems make your app work properly.

Comment: I'm newbie in Rails and your explanation is really useful !

Comment: excellent thank you @NickGinanto - would you also know the purpose of the Gemfile.lock?

Answer (score 11):

`Gemfile`s are configuration for [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/), which is used to manage your application's Ruby dependencies. That website includes a lot of documentation, including the [Gemfile manual page](http://gembundler.com/v1.2/man/gemfile.5.html).

Answer (score 4):

**Explanation by analogy**

You want to build a car. From scratch. You need to build: a chasis, engine, corroborator, radiator etc.

**Gems allow you to utilise car parts which other people have made before**

Everyone's who's ever built a car has needed the same things.

You needn't reinvent the wheel. Why make your own engine etc when you can get it straight off the shelf? What if you could get one of the best engines around, created by the most talented engineers in the world, without lifting a finger? Are you gonna spend a year trying to make your own?

So basically rather than make everything yourself, you write down a shopping list of all the parts you need:

- Rolls Royce Engine
- AutoLive seatbelts
- Michellin tyres.
- PIAA Night headlights
- etc etc.

That my friend, is basically your gem file!

Answer (score 1):

Your system can have lots of gems ... thus can have multiple versions of same `gem`.

A `Gemfile` specifies the list of `gems` with their `versions` that shall be used/loaded/(install if not present) whenever you run your rails application. or anything with `bundle exec . .`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what is a gem?

According to Wikipedia:

> RubyGems is a package manager for the Ruby programming language that
>   provides a standard format for distributing Ruby programs and
>   libraries

Gemfile

> A Gemfile is a file we create which is used for describing gem
>   dependencies for Ruby programs

Now, in very very simple words:

Gem can be thought of as a library which you can use in your code.
Example: [faker gem](https://github.com/stympy/faker)

Your code can use the functionality of `faker` gem to produce fake  data.

Now you can list all the gems that your project requires in the gemfile.
When you do a bundle install, all the gems in your gemfile are installed for you.