# Ruby 4.0 App isn't working after changing project name through Heroku website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

My app worked fine on my localhost and on Heroku until I tried changing the name of my project on Heroku through their website, not the CLI. Now, the app still works on my localhost but I get an Application Error and the message, *An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.*

Additionally, I was running Ruby Rails 3.2 and updated to 4.0 in the middle of my project to stay as up to date as possible but it's made the whole process much more complicated.

I just started coding and had this project almost finished - just needed to get it synced up with a host and my custom domain and it all went to crap :/ Any help would be very appreciated.

Here is what I get when I run Heroku logs --tail:

```
2013-10-19T04:45:55.858947+00:00 heroku[run.8369]: State changed from starting to up
2013-10-19T04:46:00.106324+00:00 heroku[run.8369]: Process exited with status 0
2013-10-19T04:46:00.144464+00:00 heroku[run.8369]: State changed from up to complete
2013-10-19T04:46:06.146445+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=lit-basin-5401.herokuapp.com fwd="98.197.58.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-19T04:46:06.983600+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=lit-basin-5401.herokuapp.com fwd="98.197.58.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-19T04:46:06.757189+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=lit-basin-5401.herokuapp.com fwd="98.197.58.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-19T04:49:11.041661+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-10-19T04:49:16.507236+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec 
rails server thin -p 51640 -e $RACK_ENV`
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896050+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896050+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896050+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896050+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896050+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896050+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896050+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896050+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896050+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896050+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896278+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:63:in `start'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896278+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896278+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896278+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `server'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896278+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896278+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.896278+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-10-19T04:49:19.911301+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-10-19T04:49:21.448808+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-10-19T04:49:21.452988+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-10-19T05:05:09.305097+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.crt.com fwd="98.197.58.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-19T05:05:09.911911+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=www.crt.com fwd="98.197.58.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-19T05:05:10.312640+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=www.crt.com fwd="98.197.58.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-19T05:05:17.288098+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=crt.herokuapp.com fwd="98.197.58.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-19T05:05:18.112302+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=crt.herokuapp.com fwd="98.197.58.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-19T05:05:18.535047+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=crt.herokuapp.com fwd="98.197.58.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-19T05:07:35+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-10-19T05:08:04.559035+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy ce44379 by sunghoster@gmail.com
2013-10-19T05:08:04.583465+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v17 created by sunghoster@gmail.com
2013-10-19T05:08:04.830493+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-10-19T05:08:08.815396+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 58476 -e $RACK_ENV`
2013-10-19T05:08:04+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044510+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044510+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044510+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044510+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044510+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044510+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044708+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044510+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044708+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044510+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044708+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `server'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044708+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:63:in `start'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044708+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044708+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044510+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044708+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.044510+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
2013-10-19T05:08:11.057865+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-10-19T05:08:12.143057+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-10-19T05:08:12.152853+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-10-19T05:08:12.154304+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-10-19T05:08:16.644957+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 44473 -e $RACK_ENV`
2013-10-19T05:08:20.604410+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-10-19T05:08:22.393304+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=crt.herokuapp.com fwd="98.197.58.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-19T05:08:22.599461+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=crt.herokuapp.com fwd="98.197.58.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-19T05:08:19.316804+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
2013-10-19T05:08:19.317076+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `server'
2013-10-19T05:08:19.316804+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
2013-10-19T05:08:19.317076+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
2013-10-19T05:08:19.316804+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
2013-10-19T05:08:19.316804+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2013-10-19T05:08:19.316804+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
2013-10-19T05:08:19.316804+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
2013-10-19T05:08:19.317076+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-10-19T05:08:19.317076+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2013-10-19T05:08:19.316804+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
2013-10-19T05:08:19.317076+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-10-19T05:08:19.317076+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
2013-10-19T05:08:19.329850+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-10-19T05:08:19.316804+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
2013-10-19T05:08:19.316804+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
2013-10-19T05:08:19.316804+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
2013-10-19T05:08:19.317076+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:63:in `start'
2013-10-19T05:08:20.589816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-10-19T05:08:21.758023+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=crt.herokuapp.com fwd="98.197.58.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-19T05:09:28.445030+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec 
rake db:migrate` by sunghoster@gmail.com
2013-10-19T05:09:32.830791+00:00 heroku[run.1104]: Awaiting client
2013-10-19T05:09:32.878270+00:00 heroku[run.1104]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-10-19T05:09:33.696273+00:00 heroku[run.1104]: State changed from starting to up
2013-10-19T05:09:35.512494+00:00 heroku[run.1104]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2013-10-19T05:09:36.469621+00:00 heroku[run.1104]: Process exited with status 0
2013-10-19T05:09:36.484133+00:00 heroku[run.1104]: State changed from up to complete
2013-10-19T05:09:41.437949+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by sunghoster@gmail.com
2013-10-19T05:09:46.113833+00:00 heroku[run.8756]: Awaiting client
2013-10-19T05:09:46.146484+00:00 heroku[run.8756]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-10-19T05:09:46.930509+00:00 heroku[run.8756]: State changed from starting to up
2013-10-19T05:09:50.254973+00:00 heroku[run.8756]: Process exited with status 0
2013-10-19T05:09:50.264019+00:00 heroku[run.8756]: State changed from up to complete
2013-10-19T05:09:56.581611+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=crt.herokuapp.com fwd="98.197.58.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-19T05:09:57.396220+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=crt.herokuapp.com fwd="98.197.58.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-19T05:09:57.702612+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=crt.herokuapp.com fwd="98.197.58.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: ``require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)` -- that's an issue. do you have the gem installed?

Comment: It's in my gem file and I can confirm it's installed because I see, "Using thin (1.6.0)" when I run bundle install. Any idea why it's not recognizing it?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the name in Heroku does nothing -- but you'll have to change it in your local git repo with these lines:

```
git remote rm heroku
heroku git:remote -a newname
```

As for your errors, it seems you've got some big errors within your app. As @KepaniHaole said, you seem to have "thin" errors - do you have the gem in your [`GemFile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072880/whats-the-use-of-gemfile-in-rails)?

Comment: thanks Rich, using your solution helped me resolve the git issues. working through the LoadError now...

Comment: :) Let me know if you need any more help!