# How can I switch back to Rails 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know this shouldn't be too hard, but I literally cannot figure it out and haven't found anything. I am currently using rails 4.0.4 but want to go back to 3.whatever.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled and tried rvm but have not been able to get back to what I want.  Thanks and appreciate all help!

Comment: Did you add a .ruby-version or .ruby-gemset file?

Comment: If you install Rails in a gemset, following this guide [Installing Rails](http://railsapps.github.io/installing-rails.html), you should have no difficulty switching between versions of Rails by switching gemsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, Rails is a ruby gem , you can specify any version you want using [Gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072880/whats-the-use-of-gemfile-in-rails) , for example:

`gem 'rails' , '3.0.0'`

And simply run

`bundle install`

If you are not using Bundler , you could also do:

`gem uninstall rails`

gem install rails --version 3.0.0

Comment: if you take that road you need to get sure if all other dependencies are compatible with that rails version, especially the ones with a specific version in the Gemfile

Comment: Also, `gem uninstall railties` and remove the binary command too when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

you can run

```
gem list rails
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
rails (4.1.0.beta1, 4.0.2, 4.0.0, 3.2.15, 3.2.13, 3.2.11, 3.2.8, 3.2.6, 3.0.7)
```

to see witch rails gem you currently have installed, then use for example

```
rails _3.2.15_ new test_app
```

to generate a rails 3.2.15 application

if you don't have the version you want already installed, you can do

```
gem install rails --version 3.2.12
```