# Rails Gemfile Clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So despite the fact I've created 3 rails apps of increasing complexity on my own. I haven't deployed any of them. I decided tonight to create another app (Well really redoing an older app with some new things I've learned) and it hit me.

I really don't completely understand the gemfile, well I do but I second guess myself quite a bit. It seems obvious and straightforward, yet here I am on Stackoverflow asking for clarification or at least to ease my second guessing.

My understanding of Gemfile is as follows.

Default are gems that are gems that will persist across all environments (Test, dev, and production), test gems only live in the test environment, dev gems in the development environment, and production gems in the production environment.

Up to this point I've kinda just been throwing most of my gems in the default, but I want to correct this before I make it a habit. I like using rails' built in testing (I know, boo, hiss) and I use minitest reporters, guard minitest and minit backtrace as my helpers. I'm told best practice would be to put them and any gem related to testing in the obvious test environment. I don't think I've ever setup a test db, much less used test environment. Why wouldn't those go under the development environment? Or is it when you run tests that's using a test environment even if you didn't explicitly create one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's the use of Gemfile in rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072880/whats-the-use-of-gemfile-in-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it when you run tests that's using a test environment even if you didn't explicitly create one?

`$ rails console test` brings you to the test environment