# Error when loading caldav-icloud gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have installed the `caldav-icloud` gem. Then I've required it in my `environment.rb`

```
require "caldav-icloud"
```

But if I do `rails s` I get this error:

```
/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- caldav-icloud (LoadError)
```

How can I solve it?
Thanks

Comment: When asking questions in Stack Overflow, please avoid text speak like "smth" and try to stick to proper punctuation, grammar and formatting. It makes your question easier to read, and thus makes them more likely to get answers helping you and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make any gem available to your Rails app, you have to add it to the `Gemfile` like this:

```
gem "caldav-icloud"
```

It is not enough to just install it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14073529/421705) goes into a bit more detail what bundler and the `Gemfile` do and why this is required.