# Error using devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, bundle-install

```
gem install devise

bundle install
```

Here it doesn't show installing devise
but when i run

```
gem list
```

I find devise (4.2.0)

```
rails generate devise:install
```

> Couldn't find generator 'devise:install. Maybe you meant 'assets',
>   'test_unit:job' or ' :assets'

What made this error?

Comment: Are you using a `Gemfile`? If yes, did you include it in there as well?

Comment: No! Could you send me a process to use Gemfile

Comment: @NireshManandhar, suggest to study further than experimenting. https://www.railstutorial.org/book.

Comment: @NireshManandhar This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14073529/839086 is a great writeup on what Gemfile is, and how to use it

Comment: @Marcus Thanks for the solution... I didnt knew what gemfile was but i was using the gem file. Now i knew about it