# NameError uninitialized constant ApiAiRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, api-ai

Ruby on Rails app deployed on Beanstalk is giving me error for API AI / Dialog Flow Gem:

```
NameError
uninitialized constant MessengerHireController::ApiAiRuby
```

I have the following code in my sidekiq Worker:

```
dialog_client = ApiAiRuby::Client.new(
  :client_access_token => access_token, 
  :api_session_id => @freelancer.user.id
)
response = dialog_client.text_request msg
```

I have tested it in my regular controller and it doesnt work.

1. I have moved it out of worker and to standard controller.
2. It works on my local but not on beanstalk
3. I ran rails console on beanstalk and tried the same code and it gave me error. I manually installed gem with `gem install 'api-ai-ruby'` After which it stopped giving me NameError on console, but still doesnt work on production.
4. I checked with `gem list` and the gem is installed on production.

My Biggest hypothesis is that the app is unable to find the installed gem.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: How do you run sidekiq in production? like `sidekiq` or `bundle exec sidekiq`? The first way may not load installed gems, for example.

Comment: I moved the method to a regular controller and it still gave the same error. Hence to conclude that the problem is not with Worker.

Answer (score 0):

You need add `gem 'api-ai-ruby'` to you gemfile, and run `bundle install`,  otherwise Rails won't load it. 
See [What is the use of Gemfile in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072880/what-is-the-use-of-gemfile-in-rails)

Comment: I did those things. It works on my local, but not on the production (Beanstalk)